# Component testing Azure Functions

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions backed by a SQL database using the Entity Framework.

To ensure code correctness, I would like to perform full automated component tests on my local machine.

Injecting a connection string which points to a local database solves the SQL server issue, but I am yet to find a way to spin up a local instance of Azure Functions programmatically. As VS exposes this behavior using the “Debug” functionality, it should theoretically possible.

How do I programmatically spin up a local version of Azure Functions using a project which is located in the same solutions as my testing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS uses the Azure Functions Core Tools for running your functions locally.

You can run yourself without needing VS in the picture. By default VS downloads the core tools under `C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\<version>\func.exe`

You can run `func.exe` for help, but to launch the same way VS does it, just cd into the output folder of your project (e.g: `bin\Debug\net461\`) and run `func host start`

more docs are here: [Code and test Azure Functions locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)